# Is there any way to shift distance between zeroes of function $-10(x-[x])$ by $a$ units on x axis?

Tags: graphing-functions, transformation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

The function is
$$-10(x-[x])$$
Now i wonder if we can shift distance between zeroes of this function by a units is it possible?
[image: i tried replacing x with x-1 but it doesn't work]
I tried replacing x with x-1 but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried shifting the function itself?

Comment: Try replacing all occurrences of $x$ with $(x-a)$ to move it $a$ units in the positive x-axis direction, for integer values of $a$

Comment: Yes replacing (x) with x-a doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is periodic with period $1$, so when you replace $x$ with $x-a$, and $a$ is any whole number, the graph will look the same as the unshifted graph (because you are shifting by a multiple of the period). Try letting $a$ be something other than a whole number.

EDIT: To add on about why $f(\frac{x}{a})$ changes the period from $1$ to $a$.

We know the period of $f(x)$ is $1$, which tells us $f(x+1)=f(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain. The same is true for any function with period $1$.

Let $g(x)=f(\frac{x}{a})$. We can see that $g(x+a)=f(\frac{x+a}{a})=f(\frac xa+1)=f(\frac xa)=g(x)$.

That line of reasoning should also show that there is no number $b$, where $0<b<a$, such that $g(x+b)=g(x)$, so $a$ is the period for $f(\frac xa)$.

Comment: Sorry but i asked a wrong question i want to increase distance between zeroes of this function

Comment: $f(\frac{1}{a}\cdot x)$ will make the zeros be $a$ units apart

Comment: That will also make the period of the function be $a$ units

Comment: Drie cleaner it worked now i can express freefall as a periodic function

Comment: OP has misled us all by referring to “shifting”. He really meant “stretching”. Nowadays, the technique you have given in your comment is standardly taught in high-school mathematics. It certainly was not in the dear dead days when I was in high school. I do suggest that you change your answer to what’s in your comment, to take account of OP’s clarification.

Comment: Sorry sir lubin